# Fork a github repo and push to my private repo

Tags: github, fork

I am taking a class which has a classwide github repo to publish labs, docs, etc. I want to fork this, do my own work on the labs, and push to my private git repo. However, I still want to be able to pull changes from the class github. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set up two remote branches, one for your private and one to the class

```
git remote add classwide sshblah
git remote add private sshblah
```

then you can

```
git fetch classwide
```

to grab your class stuff and

```
git merge localbranch
```

to work on it, then you can

```
git push localbranch private
```

to put it into your private repo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for sure, the key is in your repo remotes, so your fork have a remote called "origin" and for the original repo create a remote called upstream.

create the upstream remote with following command

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/user/original.git
```

Then validate your remotes

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/your-user/fork.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/your-user/fork.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/user/original.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/user/original.git (push)
```

So now you can push and pull from the original repo

```
git pull upstream branch
git push upstream branch
```

In the other way you can create a pull request directly in Github

Comment: Excuse me, I make a mistake, now is fixed, is git remote add